# Mysql Duplicate Entry Before Apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm attempting to import some data with codeigniter using activerecord. I get this error which doesn't make any sense to me

```
<p>Error Number: 1062</p>
<p>Duplicate entry 'L'' for key 'brand'</p>
<p>INSERT INTO `brands` (`brand`) VALUES ('L\'awlek')</p>
```

I have a UNIQUE constraint on the brands table as I don't want duplicates. My question is, why is it cutting the value off at the first apostrophe and claiming that that's the key?

Relevant Code :

```
define('TABLE','brands');

function add( $data ){
    $exists = $this->exists( $data['brand'] );
    if( ! $exists )
        $query = $this->db->insert( TABLE , $data);

    return ! $exists ? $this->db->insert_id() : $exists;
}

function exists( $value ){

    $query = $this->db->get_where( TABLE , array('brand'=>$value));

    if( $query && $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        return $query->row()->id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the column defined as varchar(2) or something similar?

Comment: The 'brand' column is set to varchar(150)

Comment: Is the key `brand` defined with length 2?

Comment: How can I check the key length? I used SQLYog to create the table and just assigned a unique index to it

Comment: key_len for brand in the brands table is 752

Comment: Does this happen only with `L'` or with other prefixes too, like AA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help!

A fellow developer ran this perl script against the data set. I'm assuming the apostrophe was a 'smart quote'. This script removes all non-ascii characters, and it worked afterwards. Maybe it'll help someone else out there.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' data.sql
```

Comment: That would do it, an non-standard character... problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are passing the array `$data` into function `add`.

In `add`, you pass the `$data` array to the function `exists`.

In `exists`, you treat the array as a variable, and this means
that your SQL statement is not what you expect. As a result, you
are not finding your preexisting record, hence your duplicate key message.

A simple fix might be something like:

```
function exists( $data ){

    $query = $this->db->get_where( TABLE , $data);

    if( $query && $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        return $query->row()->id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**A Bit More Detail**
In the following statement, if `$value` is an array.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where( TABLE , array('brand'=>$value));
```

would evaluate to:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where( TABLE , array('brand'=>'Array'));
```

which is why your query returns false since 'Array' is not a brand in your table.

**PS**
There could be other things going on depending on the sequence of events leading up to calling your functions, but this obvious bug should be fixed before looking for other more subtle problems.

Comment: Good catch! However, I've since changed the exists check in the add function to use $data['brand'] but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Just to make sure, as a test, you are trying to insert a record that already exists is the database.  Have you tested the `exists` function independently of the `add` function?

Comment: By the way, what do the values from `$query->row()->id` look like?

Comment: It works with L'awlek inserted directly to the table. But with L\'awlek inserted instead, exists returns false when either L'awlek or L\'awlek is passed in as the argument.

Comment: The $query->row()->id values are integers, it makes it through several thousand records before breaking on this one, and several of the non-issue records have ' in them.

Comment: Originally, when you used `add` with "L'awlek", what value appeared in your table, "L\'awlek" or "L'awlek"?

Comment: Are the other non-issue records containing "'" escaped in you table, like "O\'Brien"?